# Set cookie in BeautifulSoup Python web scraper

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a python script that goes to a web page and check if there is a div with a specified id in it and if there isn't, it tries again deleting a given cookie.

So far, this is my code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'http://google.com'
cookie = 'hello'

while True:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    soup.prettify()
    if soup.find(id='hello'):
        print "Found!"
        break
    else:
        #DELETE THE GIVEN COOKIE AND TRY AGAIN
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I'm asking for is: **How do I delete the cookie? Or I don't need to delete it because BeautifulSoup will retry the request using a different instance?**

Also, is it possible to set things like headers, user agent etc with this method? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to delete the cookie here.  Every time you request the url with the urlopen() method it will request a new copy of the page.  However, if you do need to save a cookie, I recommend the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) library or mechanize which will both allow you to save browser sessions.

It is also possible to add headers and a user agent to the code you have.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'http://google.com'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

while True:
    page = opener.open(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    soup.prettify()
    if soup.find(id='hello'):
        print "Found!"
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```